# UITableViewCell desn't update it's heigh to fit custom UIControl height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, uicontrol

I've created a custom slider inherited from `UIControl` and pass it into `UITableViewCell`.

The problem is that when the content of my custom slider is bigger than UITableViewCell's height, the cell won't update it's height to fit slider's content height

Here is my hierarchy of TableViewCell

[image]

This is how it looks like(the background blue view is a cell). All views I created in code in custom slider control:

[image]

This is how it looks like on the device:

[image]

As you can see I have a larger content of my custom control, but the cell doesn't want to update its constraints to fit control's content. One more thing, as you can see on the first screenshot, I have height constraint >= 60, but if I remove this constraint, than my custom slider won't be visible at all:

[image]

Here is my code of custom slider, but I guess I messed something of updating constraints of parent view(UITableViewCell) or calculating setting parentView's(UITableViewCell) content height:

```
private func updateValueLabelFrame() {
    func positionForValueInTrack() -> CGFloat {
        return trackView.frame.width * ((value - minimumValue) / (maximumValue - minimumValue))
    }
    
    func originForValueInTrack(height: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        let x = positionForValueInTrack() - height / 2
        return CGPoint(x: x, y: (trackView.frame.height - height) / 2)
    }
    trackView.setNeedsDisplay()
    valueLabel.sizeToFit()
    let biggerSize = valueLabel.frame.width > valueLabel.frame.height ? valueLabel.frame.width : valueLabel.frame.height
    var valueViewHeight = self.frame.height - (self.frame.height * 0.3)
    
    if biggerSize > valueViewHeight {
        valueViewHeight = biggerSize + 20
        self.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: valueViewHeight / 0.7)
        self.setNeedsLayout()
    }
    let valueViewSize = CGSize(width: valueViewHeight, height: valueViewHeight)
    self.valueView.frame = CGRect(origin: originForValueInTrack(height: valueViewHeight), size: valueViewSize)
    
    let valueLabelSize = valueLabel.sizeThatFits(valueViewSize)
    let valueLabelOrigin = CGPoint(x: valueView.bounds.midX - valueLabelSize.width / 2, y: valueView.bounds.midY - valueLabelSize.height / 2)
    valueLabel.frame = CGRect(origin: valueLabelOrigin, size: valueLabelSize)
    
    valueView.layer.cornerRadius = valueView.frame.size.width / 2
}

private func updateFrame() {
    minimumLabel.sizeToFit()
    maximumLabel.sizeToFit()
    minimumLabel.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.minX + minMaxLabelsOffsetToBorder, y: self.bounds.midY - minimumLabel.frame.height / 2)
    maximumLabel.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.maxX - (maximumLabel.frame.width + minMaxLabelsOffsetToBorder), y: self.bounds.midY - maximumLabel.frame.height / 2)
    let trackLayerSize = CGSize(width: (maximumLabel.frame.minX - trackLayerOffsetFromLabels) - (minimumLabel.frame.maxX + trackLayerOffsetFromLabels), height: self.bounds.height / 3)
    let trackLayerOrigin = CGPoint(x: minimumLabel.frame.maxX + trackLayerOffsetFromLabels, y: self.bounds.midY - trackLayerSize.height / 2)
    trackView.frame = CGRect(origin: trackLayerOrigin, size: trackLayerSize)
    createReplicatorLayer()
    updateValueLabelFrame()
}
```

Comment: Is your custom control designed in a xib? Or all via code? Are you using constraints on the custom control's subviews to define its height?

Comment: @DonMag I made my control all via code. No, I'm using constraints only on my custom control in UITableVIewCell. Inside control I'm using only frame for calculating subview's location

Comment: OK - to get a table view cell to auto-size its height, you really need to be using constraints. Post your code for your custom control?

Comment: @DonMag well, I've added constraints and it works! Thanks a lot! Post you answer and I'll mark it as solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per OP...

You're missing constraints that are needed to auto-size the height of the cell.